# How can I do something like "tf.exe shelveset <shelvesetname> <username>" from VS2010 command prompt?

Tags: command-line, tfs, shelveset

I am using Visual Studio 2010, connected to Team Foundation Server.

The following command works for change sets:

```
tf changeset 12345
```

What is the equivalent command that works with a shelve set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about [TFS Command Line Utilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0.aspx) and you want to do shelve a set instead of changeset?

Well there are the `shelve` and `shelvesets` commands.

`shelve` [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6y8ezzs.aspx) and be used like so:
`tf shelve  [/replace] [/comment:("comment"|@commentfile)] [shelvesetname] [/validate][/noprompt] [/login:username,[password]]`

and [shelvesets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181451.aspx) can be worked with like so:
`tf shelvesets [/owner:ownername] [/format:(brief|detailed)] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]] [/login:username,[password]] shelvesetname`